# What is the difference between io.sockets.emit and socket.emit in io.on('connection', function(socket){})?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I noticed if I want to emit a message like

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.emit('signal')
})
```

Somehow I have to refresh the HTML page to get the ejs file work on the signal. But If I directly emit it like:

```
io.sockets.emit('signal')
```

Then I do not have to refresh the html to get the action work.

How come?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me translate the code in plain English.

**First case**

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.emit('signal')
})
```

*Translation: When `io` is being connected, instruct the connected socket that triggered the `connection` event to emit 'signal'.*

In this case, the `io` is attached with an event listener that listens for "connection" event, which is fired whenever a `socket` connects to the `io`. Therefore, whenever a `socket` connects to the `io`, the `io` instruct the `socket` to emit a "signal" event.

*Why do I need to refresh for it to fire?*

Because when you refresh, your computer acts as a `socket` and is connected to the `io` onload. Therefore a "connection" event is fired, and it is only fired when a `socket` connects to the `io`.

*Note:* Actually, you *do not* need to refresh to fire it. You can simply disconnect your internet connection and then reconnect it.

**Second case**

```
io.sockets.emit('signal')
```

*Translation: All sockets that are currently connected to `io`, emit 'signal' event now!*

In this case, you are instructing all currently connected `sockets` to emit the "signal" event. Your computer is a `socket` connected to the `io`, so it emits the event.

*Note:* If you have another device connecting to the same node server, and you use that command, you will see two "signal" events being emitted.

Answer (score 0):

In the first case you're waiting for a "connection" event.

With a refresh of your page, you'll be connected again and finally fire your event.

In the second case, the message will be sent to all clients when you'll start your server.

Answer (score 0):

Here

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
}
```

listen for the connection event for incoming sockets.

if you directly use io.sockets.emit('signal') then you must need event on connection as it check for connection establish or not.